# MySQL query - Select statement from two tables with group by returning records with largest ids

Tags: mysql, database, select, groupwise-maximum

I really need help from you, I've spend a lot of time already on trying to figure it out but without success :(

I have two tables:

> 

What I need is to group everything by sea_id / bat_season and gain the greatest Id's for these seasons. So bat_id's 3 & 5 should be returned with their linked data.
But if there is no data in Table 2 I still should see details of two seasons without Table 2 details.

My closest result is here with the below statement:

```
SELECT b.bat_id, b.bat_trophies, b.bat_ranking, s.sea_id, s.sea_name, s.sea_start 
FROM gvg_seasons s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bat_id, bat_trophies, bat_ranking, bat_season FROM gvg_battles ORDER BY bat_id DESC LIMIT 1) b 
ON s.sea_id = b.bat_season 
WHERE s.sea_gl_id = 1
GROUP BY s.sea_id DESC
```

The result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcoF4.jpg)

If someone can help me here please I will be very grateful.

Comment: Please update your question with your table data in markdown tables or SQL insert statements instead of just linking images. A table of your expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this as I didn't fancy transcribing the table data from your images but it should provide the result you are looking for.

The innermost sub-query gets the max(bat_id) per bat_season. This is joined back to the gvg_battles to give the latest battle per season.

```
SELECT *
FROM gvg_seasons s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b1.*
    FROM gvg_battles b1
    JOIN (
        SELECT bat_season, MAX(bat_id) AS max_bat_id
        FROM gvg_battles
        GROUP BY bat_season
    ) b_max ON b1.bat_id = b_max.max_bat_id
) b2 ON s.sea_id = b2.bat_season;
```